# Mandoline quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-layout

Write a quine... from which every other character can be removed it still be a valid quine. You can specify whether to start removing characters at the first or second character.

Scoring criteria (add bonuses/penatly percentages together for total percentage):

- Answers must be at least 4 characters long
- Program must contain at least one alphabetical character in its source, so for example, `12345!@#$%^&*()` is disqualified
- +750% if the language used is not Turing-complete (I'm looking at you, HTML!)
- -15% if the solution does not read its source from anywhere in any form
- -20% if you can also keep only every 5th character and still form a quine

The score is measured by the number of characters in the first program.

Example (not real programs):

If `123456789abcdef` and `13579bdf` are both quines, the score is 15. Additionally, if `159d` is also a quine, then the final score is 12.

This is code-golf, so lowest score wins.

Comment: What if a person writes their code so all the removed characters are unnecessary whitespace?

Comment: @hosch250 The original program wouldn't be a quine because it wouldn't print those whitespaces. Same goes for unnecessary comments.

Comment: Guess so.  Nice challenge.

Comment: @hosch250 hah, I personally am not very good at even writing an answer for this type of thing.... But no matter what challenge you hurl at the people here, several people will have a solution to your insanely hard problem :P

Comment: Yeah, I have never programed a quine before, and have no idea how to do it without reading the source code in C++.  I have seen them in C++ before though!

Comment: If you're giving bonuses to markup languages, which don't have an execution model, you must be using a non-standard definition of quine, and you need to include it.

Comment: You state: "-20% if you can also remove every 4 characters and still form a quine". But technically this is not what happens in your example. You mean you can do it a second time?

Comment: @mmumboss: "Remove every 4 characters" is not really grammatical, anyway, but yes, it appears to mean "remove all but every fourth character".

Comment: Are the bonuses additive or multiplicative?  That is, if my program is 10 chars long and qualifies for both the -15% bonus and the -20% bonus, will its score be 10 * (1 - 0.15 - 0.2) = 6.5 or 10 * (1 - 0.15) * (1 - 0.2) = 6.8? I assumed the latter, but an explicit clarification would be nice.

Comment: HQ9+ wins this easily.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel HQ9+ is not Turing complete (or even close), so it gets +750%. Minimum number of letters is 4, so that's 4*750%= 30. Code golf fail.

Comment: Still less than most languages can

Comment: I think HQ9+ (Q+++) also qualifies for the 20% bonus... so it scores 24.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a Mandoline quine, not a Guillotine? Guillotines make one clean, generally fatal, cut and the head rolls away. Mandolines make with the many evenly spaced slices. :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I didn't specify, but I consider it to be additive.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre I like that. I'll go change the title now :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### PHP, 4 chars − 15% − 20% = <s>2.72</s> 2.6 points

```
ABCD
```

Yes, PHP is a Turing-complete language.  Nobody said I have to *use* any of its actual programming features. ;-)

<sub>**Edit:** Changed the score based on the clarification that bonuses are additive, not multiplicative.</sub>

Comment: This works in ASP, possibly.

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ I give up. :P

Comment: Actually, use of PHP's actual programming features is discouraged.

Comment: This is not a proper quine. Still a good answer, though

Answer (score 14):

## Python - 95

Great challenge. I thought this was pretty clever, and actually a legit solution!

```python
00;"#";print(open(__file__).read())
0#;XpXrXiXnXtX(XoXpXeXnX(X_X_XfXiXlXeX_X_X)X.XrXeXaXdX(X)X)
```

Comment: Nice! Note this technically doesn't work as-is since you end up deleting the newline when making the alternate quine. requires a tad bit of tweaking IOW

Comment: @Claudiu Well I guess it depends on whether OP considers newline a character. If so, you can just add a newline between each line. 96 chars

Comment: Of course a newline is a character...

Answer (score 14):

### TI BASIC 4 - 35% = 2.6

*I might understand them wrong, but I think I am also eligible for the -15% and the -20% bonusses, meaning I have the lowest possible score.*

I can write the program:

```
123i
```

which will output `123i` where i is of course the imaginary unit. When you remove the 1st and the 3rd character all that remains is `2i` which outputs `2i`

Comment: Not quite... '12i'  will output '12i' and '2' will output '2' for a minimum score of 1.95.

Comment: Actually, '2i' scores 1.3, and if the empty program is considered a quine, 'i' scores 0.65.

Comment: @intx13: "*Answers must be at least 4 characters long.*"

Comment: Ah, I missed that!

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 11):

### Golfscript, 5 points

```
{hai}
```

is a function that, when executed, will run the (non-existing) function `hai`. It's not executed, however, but rather printed when the program ends - including the outer brackets. Removing each other character yields:

```
{a}
```

Lame, I know :-)

Comment: I believe you qualify for both bonuses, too: your program does not read its own source code, and `{}` is a quine too.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen it's hard to tell what counts as reading own source code. Does unevaluating functions count? Does evaluating strings count? As for the other bonus - maybe it's just badly worded, but I read "remove every four characters"  as "keep every fifth character", which would leave me with one bracket only (though `{ab0}` qualifies if `0` can be the one that's kept)

Comment: It's indeed badly worded, but the example suggests it means "keep every fourth character". Anyway, as you note, `{ab0}` qualifies either way.

Comment: It seems `{hi}` also works, will be shorter (4 chars), and will also qualify for all bonuses. (Seems the script `{i` evaluates to `{i` for some reason...)

Comment: @Claudiu [`{i` produces an extra closing curly for me](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e2k%3D)

Comment: What about `{{}}`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sorry for the very late reply, but it would not, since it would not contain any alphabetic character.

Comment: `{hai}` there! Does one part of the code encode another? If not, then it is not a proper quine by PPCG standards.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 `{hai}` there! Those rules came way after I answered this question. In fact, I already hadn't remembered having answered this by the time I was fighting against those rules...

Comment: As to your question proper... I haven't touched quines for several years already, so I don't remember the current definition of proper quines, and I'm not even sure they hadn't changed since I last saw them...

Comment: @JohnDvorak Okay, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 9):

### HQ9+ - 4 * 7.5 * 0.8 = 24 points

```
Q+++
```

Still a quine with every second character:

```
Q+
```

...and every fifth:

```
Q
```

Sorry, I couldn't resist. :)

Answer (score 7):

## HTML/Markdown, 4*7.5 = 30

```
HHHH
```

I admit this is lame, but it doesn't really go against any rule in the question. Except that HTML/Markdown may not be considered a real programming language.

Comment: I suppose I didn't specify that programs that can't be split any smaller aren't valid. Revising challenge...

Comment: @Jwosty: then "HHHH" in HTML would win. Note `5555` doesn't work because it has no alphabetic character

Comment: You need an alphabetic character.

Comment: @qwr: Forgot that when looking at GolfScript. Removed.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose that this valid :P

Comment: `4*7.5 = 30`...

Comment: @Bakuriu: The score is maintained by the participants in this question, not me.

Answer (score 5):

## !/bin/sh

I liked [qwr's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23306/mandoline-quine#23311) so much, I shamelessly made a port for POSIX shell.  Please don't save it into a filename containing spaces.

```
: '#';cat $0

#c a t   $ 0
```

Start removing at character number 1, and count newlines as characters.  The second quine is of course:

```
 #;a 0
cat $0
```

*Please upvote qwr's answer instead of this one!*

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 23

Newline is a character!

Some messy comment work, so that when every other character starting from the first is removed, the comment becomes code and the code becomes a comment:

```
#cRaRtR R$R0R R#
cat $0
```

After every other character (*including the new line*) is removed:

```
cat $0 #ct$
```

Comment: it's not a quine if it reads its own source though.

Comment: @daniero "-15% if the solution does not read its source from anywhere in any form" implies that you *are* allowed to read the program's source (but you don't get the bonus)

Comment: @daniero oh i looked on wikipedia I suppose it is cheating... but it's [tag:code-golf]

Comment: I always upvote cats!

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes -15% = 6.8

```
` I,` I,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgIEksYCBJLCIsIiIsIiJd)

### Every other char

```
`I`I
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgSWBJIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### Explanation :

```
` I,`    # push ` I,`
      I  # quote and prepend
       , # print

`I`  # push `I`
   I # quote and prepend
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

### Brainf**k, 37 - 15% = 31.45

Abusing the [Portable Brainfuck Interpreter](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/brainfuck/pbi.c)

```
+A[B-C<D+E]F-GÿH<I<J<K<L<M<N<O[P.Q>R]
```

Start removing from the second character.

Comment: When i run this I get `B-C<D+E]F-GÿH<I<J<K<L<M<N<O[P.Q>R]` as output so it's lacknig some characters.

Comment: Is it Brainfuck, or a particular dialect of Brainfuck that only works on one interpreter?

Comment: @immibis It's regular (those capital letters can be spaces or symbols or anything). However, you must use the portable interpreter linked from the answer.

Comment: The first part goes left until it finds the ÿ and the linked interpreter happens to store the code 5000 bytes before the start of the data tape. That's hardly portable Brainfuck.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>145</s> 94 bytes -15% : Score = 79.9

```python
s ="'psr=i%nrt;(p'rsi n=t%(rs;%e%xse)c;(xsc[s11:::2  2']; p)r'i%nst)(#s#%#s#)";exec(s[1:: 2] )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY0xCsMwDEX3nEIoGFuFQONuMe5FgifX0CyukTykp3fdhkKXDgLp6z9eedb7I19afNySZ0RsAh51EfabylydKZplg@yrMixOJbVLoujMLnGVeV6WxQJYHRwUYt0hqWRGGVUfQpf2FI2svQc2ALWu6Mc0h2EovOVq3mZyx47@ijR8kCP@lnDCkz3TL7N2cfgDHr/2Ag)

### every other char:

```python
s='s=%r;print(s%%s);xcs1:2 ';print(s%s);xcs1:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fnJ@SalukpKT0v9hWvdhWtci6oCgzr0SjWFW1WNO6IrnY0MpIQR0uiBD7D9QTbWilaxjLxQWRBRmlCVWppKukZWSgyZVakZoMkfgPAA)

### How it works :

The ugly string is the blending of :

- `print('s =%r;exec(s[1::2 ] )'%s)####` for the normal quine
- `'s=%r;print(s%%s);xcs1:2 ';print(s%s)` for the every-other-char quine

`xcs1:2`  is an annotation and doesn't throw any error as the part after the semicolumn can compile. Otherwise it would throw a `SyntaxError` and the program wouldn't run at all.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), with reading code source: <s>70</s> 62 bytes

```python
s ="p-r-i-n-t-(-*-o-p-e-n-(-_-_-f-i-l-e-_-_-)-)";exec(s[::2] )
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BCsIwEETP7leEPWWFBVtvKf2SUkTaLQZqEtII@vUxbU@CguxlZgfmTXilm3fnPPhR2oiIeVEtBo5s2XFizUf2HFiK03wpN5VkLn7VxISNPGXQS2dM3SvKpaKrDFc9wCiT8kGcnuws7noXMnCIkh7RKZsk6m6l9gQQonVJr46aXSPjsT4RbOXfgj/bt1mfiO31k7OnAPkN)

### every other char:

```python
s=print(*open(__file__));xcs:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsMgEEXXnVOIKycQaNKdIScJQYqZUKEdZWIhPb2tdfcf//HSJz8i34qPG82itS7HnCRwNl1MxMa5PTzJOcTp9IcdVfk5y2D7YQXYaFd/qzp8fxFauAjlt7AKmcQsNbsiQEtWwqlt3etuvCLQSb4dUL4)

Answer (score 0):

## HQ9+T, - 4 * 0.8 = 3.2 points

```
qqqq
```

It's a valid quine (ish) and a quine every second and fifth char.
I couldn't resist . . . .