# Radiation softened quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, radiation-hardening

It's simple: Make a [proper](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/8478) quine where if you remove any character, it's still a quine.

The difference between this and a radiation hardened quine is that if your program is `AB`, in a radiation hardened quine `A` would output `AB`, but here, `A` would output `A`.

Code golf, all standard rules, standard loopholes apply, no cheating.

Comment: Is an empty program valid?

Comment: @Loovjo [No.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5337/8478)

Comment: Does the original program need to be a quine? I.e. in the example, is it enough that `A` outputs `A` and `B` outputs `B`, or is it also necessary that `AB` outputs `AB`?

Comment: @feersum The challenge states "Make a quine where...", so `AB` should output `AB`.

Comment: @Mego I know it says that, but specifications are not always so precise, and it is not indicated in the examples.

Comment: @feersum "Make a quine" means make a quine. "The difference between this and a radiation-hardened quine..." means that the *only* difference is that the program with any one byte removed results in a quine, not a program that prints the original program's source. There is no ambiguity here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## ><> (Fish), <strike>145</strike> 107 bytes

This answer uses ><>'s jumping instruction to fix the problem.

```
!<0078*+00~..>0[!."r43a*+8a+&{ee+00&1-:&(?.~~ol?!;4b*0.0f<>0['r3d*159*+&}7a*00&1-:&(?.~~ol?!;68a*+0.0+*a58
```

This quine actually contains two different quine generators. It starts with some jumping logic and by default uses the left quine. If a character is removed from the jumping logic or from the left quine, the program jumps to the right quine.

[You can try it here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/cz5Wrfmy7QG4mq3w7)

## Explanation

The code can be dissected into a few parts:

```
A: !<0078*+00~..>0[!. 
B:              >0[!."r43a*+8a+&{ee+00&1-:&(?.~~ol?!;4b*0.
C:                                                    .0f<
D:                                                        >0['r3d*159*+&}7a*00&1-:&(?.~~ol?!;68a*+0.
E:                                                                                                 .0+*a58
```

Explanation of the different parts:

- A: Jumps to the right of C. If any character is deleted from from A,
  this jumps to the left of D or the right of E, triggering the second
  quine.
  If any character is deleted from B or C, the code is shifted 1
  character to the left, causing this to jump to the left of D.
- C: This code jumps to the left of B.
- B: Quine #1
- D: Quine #2
- E: Jumps to the left of D

## Explanation of the quine (with #1 as example):

Once the instruction pointer reaches either of the quines, you're certain that that quine is completely intact.

```
>0[!.                                       //Fix the instruction pointer's direction and empty the stack (The '!.' is a leftover from codepart A)
     "r43a*+                                //Start reading all of the code and add the '"' character to the stack
            8a+&                            //Because the quine started reading at the 19th character instead of the first, the stack has to move 18 characters. 
                                            //This part saves the number 18 to the register.
                {ee+00&1-:&(?.              //Move the stack one to the left, decrease the stack by 1. If the stack is not empty yet, jump back to the start of this section.
                              ~~              //Clean the temporary variables from the stack. It should now contain the whole quine.
                                ol?!;4b*0.  //Print the first character from the stack. As long as the stack isn't empty, jump back to the start of this section.
```

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: Reiterating above.

Comment: Is this clear enough?

Answer (score 37):

## [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), 4.54×10<sup>761</sup> bytes

It has this number of null characters:

> 453997365974271498471447945720930600149036031871190716908688344432973027776681259141680552038829875159204621651993092104775733418288411812715164994750890484868305218411129600012389568016974351721147925344946382782884546247102886167837964612372737300786173159265347137401863281368021545169383664534228503236761742285358985343373496184959796553930661837467682191561275123057706776367104142995491262443697167483190110516522677811931124842961701222425076750211774387637740969301686178545299089832300154448308384461700726890067468872402133010536518468336342175124002115991866466700174974019423711837589532744970385003356612639263433822126850314801275940879069069974437167102618471264140597777702065896715558989678487253830854848740247786166790545462769498303055791292

Seeing how the criterion in this challenge conflicts with the definition of a "proper quine", seriously, I think an Unary variant is going to win.

Expanded Brainfuck code:

```
>>+++>++++++++>+++>+++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>++++++++>++++>++++++++>++++>+++++++>++>+++>+>+++>++>+++>+++>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>+>++++>++++>+++++++>+>++++>++++++++>++>+++++++>+++>++++++++>++>+++++++>+++>++++++++>++>+++++++>+++>++++++++>++>+++++++>+++>+++++>++++++++>++++>+++++++>+++++++>+>+>+++>+>+>+>++++++++>+++>+++++++>+>+++>+>+++>+>+++>+>++++++++>++++>++++++++>++++>++++++++>++++>++++>+>+++>+++>++>+++++++>+++++++>+>+>+>++++++++>+++>+>++++++++>++++>+>+++>++>+++++++>++>+++++++>++++>++++>++++++++>+++>++++++++>+++>+++>+>++++>++++>++>+++++++>+++>+++>++++++++>++++>+>+++>++>+++++++>++++>++++>+++++++>+++>+++>+++>+++>++++++++>++++>++++>+>+++>+>+++>++>+++++++>+++++++
[
    [->+>+<<]
    >>>>[<<[->+<]>>[-<<+>>]>]
    <<[-[->+<]+>]+++
    [[->>+<<]<]<
]
+>+>+>+
[>]+++>++
[
    [<].
    >[-]>[-]>[-]>[-]
    <+[<<++++++++>>->+>-[<]<]
    ++++++++>++++++++>+++++++>>
]
.
```

If one character is removed from the Lenguage program, the last character becomes a `<`, which causes the program to print exactly one less character.

Comment: How did you manage to find that fixed point? (Or alternatively, how does the Brainfuck code work?)

Comment: @MartinBüttner The first big loop copies and encodes the data in the form of ">+++..." (and reverses it). The other big loop print the data as an integer in unary. It's not that complicated but is long only because it's Brainfuck.

Comment: Oh right, so it's just like a plain Brainfuck quine, but with a different decoding function?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Somewhat. But half of the program is the "decoding function".

Comment: It seems you could use a similar technique to construct answers of arbitrary score for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57257/8478 (although how exactly that works would depend on the answer to my latest comment).

Comment: @lirtosiast It is a true quine. The first line in the Brainfuck code encodes the rest. (Or the number of whole segments consisting of 8^155 null characters encodes other null characters, if you prefer that.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Technically, it says the program should work only when exactly n characters are removed, but not less, so you can get an arbitrary n. But still, it says *least* `program_length^2/n` wins, where a long program like this doesn't have much advantage.

Comment: @jimmy23013 yeah, the scoring was changed after my comment.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Last time I checked it I believed that it must also work if less than n characters are removed. In that case it can only get a score of 3, or the final character would become an unmatched `]`, making the program invalid.

Comment: How would one include a payload on this quine?

Comment: @lirtosiast Insert code before the second loop in the Brainfuck code. The memory is the Brainfuck code with the instructions represented by 1 to 8, with some delimiters.