# A Radiation Hardened Palindromic Quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, palindrome, radiation-hardening

There are radiation hardened quines, palindromic quines, but has anyone tried both?!
I think not!

### Rules

So the challenge here is to make a quine that if any symbol is deleted it prints its *original* source code, *and* the quine needs to be the same read forward and backwards(before radiation damage)! All code will be scored based on *bytes* required to write it.

### Things to avoid

1. Do not use any programs that are capable of directly examining their code and outputting it (that even means programs that take their source and dump it into some sort of data)
2. Do not use *anything* that somehow cheats all of this (like a function that outputs itself and some other character... please)

***DO YOUR BEST!!!***

Comment: Welcome to the site! I would recommend changing "things to avoid" to "these are not allowed". Generally, "requirements" work better on this site than "recommendations", since you can usually save bytes by ignoring recommendations. Also, point 3 doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If every program must be palindromic and hardy, then you're only scoring based off length.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll make sure to use recommendations from now on, also I see now that i was being repetitive! Hopefully now it looks better and makes sense

Comment: @KrystosTheOverlord Maybe you misunderstood something, requirements are better than recommendations here.

Comment: Oh, now i see, I feel like an idiot. Thanks for pointing that out, I'm still a little new to all of this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 78 bytes

```
\<"2ss}}l2%?:}a`(:&K&:&]r&[r~H>.!01<<\

\<<10!.>H~r[&r]&:&K&:(`a}:?%2l}}ss2"<\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/P8ZGyai4uLY2x0jV3qo2MUHDSs1bzUottkgtuqjOw05P0cDQxiaGiyvGxsbQQFHPzqOuKFqtKFYNrEwjIbHWyl7VKKe2trjYSMkm5v9/AA)

[Verification!](https://tio.run/##fZHNTsMwEITP8VNsi4gTASkpNxNAggsSR45pBFbqtBbBttYOVQ/h1cumf3AAbra8Mzvz2a3D0pqrjX53FgNYzxzaBcp3uAHknG9mxXjqfd@309M70cvXRMRPsYgrjEv8fLzNRpd5UcwYmxVFfjnKbh8/sYyxirdjyavsxd3ptO1776fjYrYhyzIXF3lFe7QJCb9fBwW17UwQ/BxaZZJ9gEyZ2s5VwqWvteZpmjI2Vw1gZ15a68PLfu4wnwoWrXRYgnVkwgctGfIVT0F6aOg1arIV6qCOChahCh0aqp25rawZux0QmFgXJgvbNtovJx7rwzlzaxi8x2mGSs4TSiW9V8TuCO7mcCzFtimzXRhw/hX8YLAdO4oZI0Tq42EpkcScXzPWWAQN2gBKs1DJD1jp0F43x8W6gtHgtNMLgBN4ftMO9FyZoGvZUgfjVd0F/UH4aUbWQaEnSP@HLQVZn33vOctFRRyjk913kni4/V4oin4U@k7KNl8)

A variation on the [radiation hardened quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179196/76162) I posted yesterday. It's a little more complex since it needs to reverse the copied section using the undocumented `[]` operators, as well as redirect the pointer in one copy. If you're a little confused about why it doesn't look like a palindrome, remember that `><>` is a palindrome itself.